Pronouns that refer to "team" (American English)

The team is in Detroit this weekend. They expect to win.

[Swan: Practical English Usage]
Is it possible to replace They with “It” in American English?
The combination of is and They seems inconsistent to me. Perhaps, They, in effect, refers to the members of "The team" rather than "The team".
[Edit] I assume that the following sentence is correct and sounds natural in American English.
The team expects to win.

Using "it" would sound extremely odd to me (native of the western US). Teams are a plural collectives and the members have intentions, both points militate against using "it".

When you have a group of people known by a collective noun - sports teams, musical groups, etc - there are choices in how you refer to them. Most commonly, the choice is whether to refer to them singularly or in the plural, which depends on whether you want to emphasise the individuality of the members or not. For example:

Coldplay is a band
Coldplay are going on tour

However, if the name itself is a plural term then that dictates how they are referred to:

Manchester United is an English football team
The Detroit Lions are an American football team

Although you can refer to a group noun as "it" to emphasise that it is an entity in itself, doing so removes the human element. For example, you could say "The Lakers won its first game of the season". However, your example is about expectation, which refers to human hopes. It doesn't sound at all correct to say "it expects to win", because the team as an entity does not have expectations - the people in it do.

OP has enquired regarding the collective noun "team".

Is  it possible to replace "they" with “It” in American English?

As stated in the post

We use the plural verb when we refer to each member of the team                "The team are all wearing their uniforms." (It means each team member is wearing a uniform.)
We  use the singular verb when referring to the team as a single unit or entity: "The team is putting a lot of efforts.

Similarly we can use both pronouns "it"  and "they" to refer to "the team."  For example:
The team is playing well this season. It has gone to Detroit to play the championship.
However,
"They expect to win" is more common and natural in everyday conversation.
Explanation.
"Expect" is  a verb of perception, and it's more commonly used with plural subjects or pronouns that refer to individuals, like "they" or "we". This is because expectations are typically held by individuals or groups of individuals, rather than impersonal entities.
Using "it" with "expect" can sound less natural because "it" implies an impersonal or inanimate subject, whereas expectations are typically associated with personal entities.
